# I'm trying to communicate between my Spinner and Radio button in RecyclerView Adapter with Viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm also most done with my shopping list project but I encountered a problem. I need to get 2 pieces of info:

- a bool to see if my radio button is checked;
- a string of my    location name.

The complication is that I want to update my SQLite DB using the ROOM architecture from my fragment. I am unable to perform an update to my DB as **my fragment holds the reference to my ViewModel** and **my adapter holds the reference to my spinner and radio button**. I want to be able to perform DB functions when my recyclerview appears in my fragment. I've tried interfaces and getter methods but can't seem to solve this problem. Please help!

here is my card layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_groceries_item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample location"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textview_groceries_item_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_groceries_item_name" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_full_trolley"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/trolley_cart_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/full_shopping_cart_small"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_shop_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radio_full_trolley" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

here is my recyclerview adapter:

```
public class GroceriesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceriesListAdapter.GroceriesItemHolder> {
    private List<GroceriesListItem> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> shopNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> shopNameSpinnerAdapter;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GroceriesItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //example list to fill spinner, will be changed in the future
        shopNames.clear();
        shopNames.add("SuperMarket");
        shopNames.add("Green Grocer");
        shopNames.add("Dollar Shop");
        shopNames.add("Asian Market");
        shopNames.add("Other");

        View groceriesItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout_groceries_item, parent, false);
        shopNameSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(parent.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, shopNames);
        shopNameSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        return new GroceriesItemHolder(groceriesItemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GroceriesListAdapter.GroceriesItemHolder holder, int position) {
        GroceriesListItem currentGroceryItem = ingredientsList.get(position);
        holder.textViewGroceriesItemName.setText(currentGroceryItem.getItemToBuy());
        holder.placesSpinner.setAdapter(shopNameSpinnerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ingredientsList.size();
    }

    public void setGroceriesList(List<GroceriesListItem> ingredientsList) {
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class GroceriesItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewGroceriesItemName;
        private Spinner placesSpinner;
        private TextView textViewLocation;
        private RadioButton trolleyCartStatus;

        public GroceriesItemHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewGroceriesItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_groceries_item_name);
            **placesSpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spin_shop_name);**
            textViewLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_textView);
            **trolleyCartStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_full_trolley);**
        }
    }

    //this is for deleting the item in the fragment -- completed
    public GroceriesListItem getListItemAt(int position) {
        return ingredientsList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Here is my fragment:

```
public class GroceriesListFragment extends Fragment {

private ScheduleViewModel scheduleViewModel;
private GroceriesListViewModel groceriesListViewModel;
private RecyclerView groceriesRecyclerView;
private List<String> listOfCurrentMeals = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final GroceriesListAdapter groceriesListAdapter = new GroceriesListAdapter();
    groceriesListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(GroceriesListViewModel.class);

    scheduleViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ScheduleViewModel.class);
    scheduleViewModel.getMealSchedule().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<MealSchedule>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<MealSchedule> currentMealSchedule) {

            //get all meals into a list and remove Not decided entries -- completed
            for (MealSchedule oneDaysMeals : currentMealSchedule) {
                String breakfastDish = oneDaysMeals.getBreakfastMeal();
                String LunchDish = oneDaysMeals.getLunchMeal();
                String DinnerDish = oneDaysMeals.getDinnerMeal();
                if (breakfastDish.equals("Not Decided")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    listOfCurrentMeals.add(breakfastDish);
                }
                if (LunchDish.equals("Not Decided")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    listOfCurrentMeals.add(LunchDish);
                }
                if (DinnerDish.equals("Not Decided")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    listOfCurrentMeals.add(DinnerDish);
                }
            }

            //get current Groceries list and refresh list if changed -- completed
            if (listOfCurrentMeals.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No items to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                groceriesListViewModel.clearList();
                for (String dishNames : listOfCurrentMeals) {
                    scheduleViewModel.getOneDishItem(dishNames).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<Dish>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Dish dish) {
                            groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient1(), false, ""));
                            if (!dish.getIngredient2().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient2(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient3().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient3(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient4().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient4(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient5().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient5(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient6().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient6(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient7().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient7(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient8().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient8(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient9().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient9(), false, ""));
                            }
                            if (!dish.getIngredient10().isEmpty()) {
                                groceriesListViewModel.insertIngredient(new GroceriesListItem(dish.getIngredient10(), false, ""));
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //get list of ingredients and observe changes
    groceriesListViewModel.getCurrentList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<GroceriesListItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final List<GroceriesListItem> groceriesListItems) {
            groceriesListAdapter.setGroceriesList(groceriesListItems);
        }
    });

    View groceriesListFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_groceries_list, container, false);
    groceriesRecyclerView = groceriesListFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.groceries_list_recyclerview);
    groceriesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    groceriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(groceriesListAdapter);

    //swipe to delete function -- completed
    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            groceriesListViewModel.deleteIngredient(groceriesListAdapter.getListItemAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(groceriesRecyclerView);

    //clear list function -- completed
    final Button clearListButton = groceriesListFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.clear_list_button);
    clearListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            groceriesListViewModel.clearList();
        }
    });

    //how to create a method with reference to spinner and radio button?

    return groceriesListFragmentView;
}
```

}